# NativeScript.framework.dSYM for iOS runtime 7.0.4

Tags: ios, crash, nativescript, dsym, symbolicate

Does any one know were to get the Nativescript.framework.dSYM for iOS runtime version 7.0.4?  The releases only go up to 6.5.2 at https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/releases.

I need to symbolicate an iOS crash log and need to extract the dSYM on my Mac to do that.